# How do we call the server icon as a embed thumbnail?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a 'server information' command for my bot. However, it has refused to work with everything I have tried. Does anyone know how to send the icon of the server the bot's command is sent in via an `embed`?

My code:

```
@bot.command(name='serverinfo', help='Information on your current server.')
async def support(ctx, *args, user: discord.Member = None):
    if user is None:
        user = ctx.author
    

    embed = discord.Embed(title="**Server Information**", color=0x0d48a6)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon_url(format="png"))
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Notes:

- Some removed to show where my main issue is
- User is for printing the UserID as the footer

Comment: What's the error? I think `embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon_url` will work. I don't think that is a method.

Answer (score 1):

You simply pass the url, not a png, not a jpg, simply an url

```py
embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon_url)
```